# Python не видит модули, не все, часть видит, часть нет

Tags: python, pywin32

```
PS C:\Users\24072> pip list
Package   Version
--------- -------
av        11.0.0
**Cypyonate** 1.3.1
inlineasm 0.0.3
pip       24.0
psutil    5.9.8
Pymem     1.13.1
pywin32   306
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\24072\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\import pywin32.py", line 1, in <module>
    import Cypyonate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Cypyonate'
```

модуль установлен, много раз переустанавливал не помогло.
У меня windows 11, в чем может быть проблемы?

Comment: Ну например в том, что вы зачем-то пишете его с большой буквы?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос инструкции которыми устанавливали модуль, и его официальную страницу или гитхаб